# Inherit or wrap a class that deals with concurrency

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, mocking, moq

In trying to provide a unit-testable (using Moq) abstraction of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` I am debating whether I lose the benefits of using the framework's `ConcurrentQueue<T>` implementation depending on how I author the abstraction.

What are the implications of doing one or the other in the following code listing:

```
public abstract class MyMessageQueue1<T> : ConcurrentQueue<T>
{
    public new virtual void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        base.Enqueue(item);
    }
}

public class MyMessageQueue2<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _concurrentQueue = 
        new ConcurrentQueue<T>();

    public virtual void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _concurrentQueue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```

In the first implementation (`MyMessageQueue1`), I hide any of the base class methods as to provide my implementation before passing the call to the base class.

In the second implementation, I wrap the `ConcurrentQueue<T>`inside and pass calls to it when I need to.

Does `MyMessageQueue2` have to manually handle concurrency or does it not matter as all calls are passed to the wrapped `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Comment: Why are you actually doing this at all, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: +1 Ended up being a good question @TrevorPilley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to handle concurrency in either case because all you do is just delegating calls to the ConcurrentQueue as has been stated by @nanda. However, it would help us to know your reason to wrap this class. It is fairly unit-testing friendly in the sense that it doesn't use any external resources like files or a database. When being used in your classes you can just leave it doing its job and rather testing your own functionality that uses the ConcurrentQueue.

If you are trying to wrap it because you would like to verify whether your methods use it in desired way, you are probably focusing on testing of implementation of your method rather than the method's behaviour. Which might be useful in certain scenarios but you have to be aware of that fact and it is not a common practise.

There is one thing that you are losing when writing wrappers like these. Because wrappers have virtual methods so that they can be mocked, methods can't be inlined and a bit of performance is lost. ConcurrentQueue is slim and fast class and this might actually be an issue.

Comment: Thank you. In asking for the actual intent you and @nanda made me question myself and in the end I did not need the ConcurrentQueue implementation to be tested. I was indeed only testing the _design_ of the class and not the *behaviour*. So +1 to both of you. I will mark this as the answer as it adds onto what nanda say by adding that testing implementation of the method isn't always necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If all the wrapper does is delegation to ConcurrentQueue, and the wrapper does not have it's own members to protect for concurrent access then there is nothing to be done for concurrency for your wrapper.

But what would you be unit testing on this thin wrapper?